# InvalidOperationException when trying to do SignInAsync

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-identity

I am trying to sign a user in, in a normal controller. I have something along the lines of:

```
var claims = new List<Claim>
{
    new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Subject, "xxx-xxx-xx-xxx),
    new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.PreferredUserName, "someusername"),
    new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Email, "foo@bar"),
    new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.EmailVerified, "foo@bar:),
    new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.IdentityProvider, "idsvr"),
};

var ci = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "password", JwtClaimTypes.PreferredUserName, JwtClaimTypes.Role);
var cp = new ClaimsPrincipal(ci);
await HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync("myscheme", cp);
```

And I get an exception saying `InvalidOperationException: name claim is missing`

In the constructor of the ClaimsIdentity I specified my name claim to be `JwtClaimTypes.PreferredUsername` (which is "preferred_username")

If I do add a name claim to my claims list, then sign in works fine with the above code snippet. However we actually don't have name claims in our system. We want to use the "preferred_username" as the name claim in the abstractions.

Comment: Post the configuration code where you set the claims options for Identity?

Comment: I dont understand where this might be set? maybe this is what I'm missing.